# Fast parsing of JSON with large skippable regions

Tags: java, json, text-parsing

I have a JSON that has a following structure (real world example is here https://gist.github.com/PavelPenkov/3432fe522e02aa3a8a597020d4ee7361):

```
{
  "metadata": { /* Huge TYPED object */ },
  "payload": { /* Small flat UNTYPED object */
    "field_1": 1
    "field_2": "Alice"
  }
}
```

I want to extract `payload` part as fast as possible, the file is huge and parsing it into case class is rather slow (5000 op/s on my laptop). So far I've tried

1. Parse the whole document into case class with Jackson.
2. Parse into AST with Jackson and extract only `payload` field - slightly faster.
3. `scala-jsoniter` while it probably can parse the typed part faster, it's unable to parse untyped fields by design.

Are there any other options accessible from Java or (preferrably) Scala?

Comment: Hrrmm, what would happen if you made a java class (json contract) without the metadata field? Would jackson still process any of that data? Intrigue question

Comment: Jackson will build the whole AST anyway which is the most expensive operation here

Comment: That JSON in the referenced gist really isn't that big at all. If that is the real JSON you're working with, I think your performance problem might be elsewhere.

Comment: ... How are you reading the file?

Comment: Would using something like this help? https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Comment: Assuming the structure is well understood you could also make this work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43328372/fast-efficient-way-to-read-large-json-files-line-by-line-in-java

Comment: @Mapsy the messages aren't big, it's just they have tons of useless fields. The application's performance is acceptable (it handles 500Mbit/s of traffic on 2 cores) but I want to push it to the limit. According to profiler significant amount of time is spent parsing JSON (as I said before, it's parsed at only 5000 op/s)

Comment: @JustinTamblyn, thanks I'll try the `JsonPath`. If it works the same way XSLT processors work, it should be faster. Writing my own stream parser is a thing I want to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skipping of unwanted JSON value is where jsoniter-scala shines. Yes, it doesn't provide AST model for JSON, but you can build it for yourself or use one provided by a 3rd party library. Here is an example of the custom codec for circe AST:

```
package io.circe

import java.util

import com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.core._
import io.circe.Json._

object CirceJsoniter {
  implicit val codec: JsonValueCodec[Json] = new JsonValueCodec[Json] {
    override def decodeValue(in: JsonReader, default: Json): Json = {
      var b = in.nextToken()
      if (b == 'n') in.readNullOrError(default, "expected `null` value")
      else if (b == '"') {
        in.rollbackToken()
        new JString(in.readString(null))
      } else if (b == 'f' || b == 't') {
        in.rollbackToken()
        if (in.readBoolean()) Json.True
        else Json.False
      } else if ((b >= '0' && b <= '9') || b == '-') {
        new JNumber({
          in.rollbackToken()
          in.setMark() // TODO: add in.readNumberAsString() to Core API of jsoniter-scala
          try {
            do b = in.nextByte()
            while (b >= '0' && b <= '9')
          } catch { case _: JsonReaderException => /* ignore end of input error */} finally in.rollbackToMark()
          if (b == '.' || b == 'e' || b == 'E') new JsonDouble(in.readDouble())
          else new JsonLong(in.readLong())
        })
      } else if (b == '[') {
        new JArray(if (in.isNextToken(']')) Vector.empty
        else {
          in.rollbackToken()
          var x = new Array[Json](4)
          var i = 0
          do {
            if (i == x.length) x = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(x, i << 1)
            x(i) = decodeValue(in, default)
            i += 1
          } while (in.isNextToken(','))
          (if (in.isCurrentToken(']'))
            if (i == x.length) x
            else java.util.Arrays.copyOf(x, i)
          else in.arrayEndOrCommaError()).to[Vector]
        })
      } else if (b == '{') {
        new JObject(if (in.isNextToken('}')) JsonObject.empty
        else {
          val x = new util.LinkedHashMap[String, Json]
          in.rollbackToken()
          do x.put(in.readKeyAsString(), decodeValue(in, default))
          while (in.isNextToken(','))
          if (!in.isCurrentToken('}')) in.objectEndOrCommaError()
          JsonObject.fromLinkedHashMap(x)
        })
      } else in.decodeError("expected JSON value")
    }

    override def encodeValue(x: Json, out: JsonWriter): Unit = x match {
      case JNull => out.writeNull()
      case JString(s) => out.writeVal(s)
      case JBoolean(b) => out.writeVal(b)
      case JNumber(n) => n match {
        case JsonLong(l) => out.writeVal(l)
        case _ => out.writeVal(n.toDouble)
      }
      case JArray(a) =>
        out.writeArrayStart()
        a.foreach(v => encodeValue(v, out))
        out.writeArrayEnd()
      case JObject(o) =>
        out.writeObjectStart()
        o.toIterable.foreach { case (k, v) =>
          out.writeKey(k)
          encodeValue(v, out)
        }
        out.writeObjectEnd()
    }

    override def nullValue: Json = Json.Null
  }
}
```

Another option, if you need just extraction of bytes of payload values, then you can use code like this to do it with rate ~300000 messages per second for the provided sample:

```
import com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.core._
import com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.macros._
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations._
import scala.reflect.io.Streamable
import scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3

case class Payload private(bs: Array[Byte]) {
  def this(s: String) = this(s.getBytes(UTF_8))

  override lazy val hashCode: Int = MurmurHash3.arrayHash(bs)

  override def equals(obj: Any): Boolean = obj match {
    case that: Payload => java.util.Arrays.equals(bs, that.bs)
    case _ => false
  }

  override def toString: String = new String(bs, UTF_8)
}

object Payload {
  def apply(s: String) = new Payload(s.getBytes)

  implicit val codec: JsonValueCodec[Payload] = new JsonValueCodec[Payload] {
    override def decodeValue(in: JsonReader, default: Payload): Payload = new Payload(in.readRawValAsBytes())

    override def encodeValue(x: Payload, out: JsonWriter): Unit = out.writeRawVal(x.bs)

    override val nullValue: Payload = new Payload(new Array[Byte](0))
  }
}

case class MessageWithPayload(payload: Payload)

object MessageWithPayload {
  implicit val codec: JsonValueCodec[MessageWithPayload] = JsonCodecMaker.make(CodecMakerConfig())

  val jsonBytes: Array[Byte] = Streamable.bytes(getClass.getResourceAsStream("debezium.json"))
}

@State(Scope.Thread)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Fork(value = 1, jvmArgs = Array(
"-server",
"-Xms2g",
"-Xmx2g",
"-XX:NewSize=1g",
"-XX:MaxNewSize=1g",
"-XX:InitialCodeCacheSize=512m",
"-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m",
"-XX:+UseParallelGC",
"-XX:-UseBiasedLocking",
"-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch"
))
@BenchmarkMode(Array(Mode.Throughput))
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
class ExtractPayloadReading {
  @Benchmark
  def jsoniterScala(): MessageWithPayload = readFromArray[MessageWithPayload](MessageWithPayload.jsonBytes)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably try the second method to just extract the payload bytes and then parse them into an AST or `Map`.

Comment: Dijon is another example of safe AST that is based on jsoniter-scala-core: https://github.com/pathikrit/dijon/blob/11644ac6555b487f9204ff2d6506d526ceb9f06f/src/main/scala/com/github/pathikrit/dijon/package.scala#L134-L192